# Wrong array output with mysqli_fetch_all

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to save all rows from a selection into an array. After that this array is converted into a JSON string via json_encode. My ajax function will get the data for display.

```
$arrSearchResponse = mysqli_fetch_all($this->_dbcon->query($sql_search),MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

My problem is the following..

I should get the JSON-String like that:

```
{"ID":"04b487b1fda303d89.43886111","ARTNUM"}
```

but the output is:

```
[{"ID":"04b487b1fda303d89.43886111","ARTNUM"}]
```

So I have an associative array inside an non associative, if I understand that right.. but why?

In the jquery I create an object of this string via jsonParse(myJSONstring) to access the fields like:

```
var obj = jsonParse(myJSONstring);
// my title = obj['title'];
```

EDIT: My corresponding jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    url:  url,
                    data: $.param(objFilterParams),
                    success: function(data) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                        $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
                           $('#searchresults').html(element.TITLE);
                        });
                    }
                    });
```

EDIT 2: Last problem. Just one row is displayed in the search results.. Dispite the fact, that I fetch all rows. The object contains all rows of data..

--> OK, I used .html() to replace the content :D maybe I should append the data ;)

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all`return an enumerated array with all the rows. If you want encode only first row, use `json_encode( $arrSearchResponse[0] )`

Comment: hmm, the docs say: "fetch_all - Fetch all rows and return the result-set as an associative array". I don't want just the first row. I want to display all search results...

Updated my post with the jquery..

Comment: yes. every **single** row is an associative array (with `MYSQLI_ASSOC` param), but they are in an enumerated array (fetch **all**) btw, if you are interested in a single row, why do not use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? it returns only one row

Comment: As I said before. I don't want to output just a single row. It's a search and I want to output every found row. My problem is, how to get rid of the enumerated array.. or how do I store all records using mysqli_fetch_assoc (because this produces the correct output) in the array.

Comment: whit one row you can have an JSON object, with multiple rows you can have only a JSON array. Update question with desired JSON with multiple rows, please.

Comment: ok, I see.. so the problem is not the array.. It's my jquery. So I have to loop through the object to get every data set.